# How can I do a loopback test?

Tags: networking, loopback

Book *Computer Networks* says

> all addresses of the form 127.xx.yy.zz are reserved for loopback
>   testing. Packets sent to that address are not put out onto the wire; they are processed locally and treated as incoming packets. This allows packets to be sent to
>   the host without the sender knowing its number, which is useful for testing.

Can you tell me how to do a loopback test in Linux, and contrast it with a non-loopback test which tests the same thing (any thing)? Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the text refers to as `number`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller by "number" the book means "IP" (likely written before IPv6).

Comment: @user1133275 that seems likely, but since Tim has the source material, I wanted to make sure we were speaking the same language.

Answer (score 2):

Simply configure whichever service you wish to test to a valid IP address within the `127.0.0.0/8` CIDR block.  Then attempt to connect to it *from the same host* at that IP address you selected.  If it works, then your loopback test succeeded.

The loopback interface and address space is only significant to network infrastructure; to an application or service an IP in the 127.0.0.0/8 block is just like any other IP address.

The difference between running a service on the loopback interface and on an "actual" network interface is that, as the quote in your question says, loopback traffic never goes out "on the wire", which is to say no data are ever transmitted beyond the host itself.

This means that if you are setting a service up on the loopback range for testing, you *must* test from the same host.  If you want to test connections from another host (so as to test network connectivity) you *must* instead bind your service to a "wire"-facing interface and address, either directly or indirectly.

Comment: Without using loopback IP address, how would you do the test instead?

Comment: I don't understand the follow-up question.  How would one test a service on a loopback IP without using the loopback IP?  That's like asking how to test a radio without.. a radio.

Comment: How would one test a service  without using the loopback IP?

Comment: By binding the service to a _non_-loopback IP and testing it on that address.

Comment: Does that mean I have to modify the source code of the service? Or is there some program like file redirection for redirecting IP address  without modifying the source of the service?

Comment: This is getting far afield of the original question.  Most services have configuration files or parameters or other means of configuring them.  If you have a specific question that this answer to the OP at the top of the page is not addressing, please edit your question to clarify the intent of your inquiry.

Comment: @Tim - this chain of comments really gives the impression that you want to try out this "loopback test" thing you heard about, without knowing anything about the service you're testing, or how you'd normally connect to or test that service. I mean, the loopback interface is just a special case, and it seems like you don't already know the general case. If that's correct, this question is probably an inefficient way to fill in the gaps.

Comment: @Useless Following your logic, if you don't know anything, if you don't have something to try on, please stop learning, don't bother to ask for a simple example. That is it,

Comment: That's really not what I said at all. I'm just saying that your question doesn't really tell us anything about the background knowledge you already have or the context in which you're reading this book. I answered using `telnet` as an example, but I have no idea whether you know what that is. I don't know if the result of telnetting to an HTTP server will mean anything to you. I don't really know if you know what I mean by "host" or "interface". If you do know those things, great, but I had to guess. If you don't, I just sparked a cascade of future questions and that isn't a good way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you tell me how to do a loopback test in Linux

```
ping -c 1 127.0.0.1
```

> , and contrast it with a non-loopback test which tests the same thing (any thing)?

```
ping -c 1 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: 1.1.1.1 is not a loopback address...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro and?

Comment: Perhaps `ping $(ip addr |  grep 'inet ' | grep -v 127.0 | awk '{ print $2 }' | cut -d/ -f1)` would be more appropriate for the non-loopback test?

Comment: @Doug I originally considered that but I have had incompatibilities with that sort of thing in the past and it over complicates the answer so I decided to leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

> tell me how to do a loopback test in Linux

Connect to a service running on the local host via loopback (in this case an HTTP server). If the server is configured to listen on all interfaces, you don't even need to reconfigure it.

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 80
```

> , and contrast it with a non-loopback test which tests the same thing (any thing)?

Connect to the same server from a different host via a real network interface (obviously, since that's the only way to get packets to communicate with a different machine).

```
$ telnet 192.168.0.100 80
```

(replace 192... with a real IP address or the network hostname)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but using `1.1.1.1` introduces a dependency on an existing IP address in Australia. Maybe `ping -c 1 google.com`?

Comment: 1.1.1.1 is not necessarily in Australia, the IP is not tied to only one server.